Runtime error when accessing GetSharedDefaultFolder of a shared Inbox
Outlook gives me a run-time error

Sorry, something went wrong. You may want to try again.

Private WithEvents InboxItems As Outlook.Items
Private WithEvents SentItems As Outlook.Items

Friend Sub Application_Startup()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set ns = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    
    Set objRecipient = ns.CreateRecipient("PLACEHOLDERNAME")
    
    Set InboxItems = ns.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objRecipient, olFolderInbox).Items
    Set SentItems = ns.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objRecipient, olFolderSentMail).Items
    
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
   MsgBox "An error occurred: " & Err.Description
    
End Sub

This ran when just accessing olFolderInbox to track when a mailitem drops into the inbox.
I added olFolderSentMail. This is where the error appears.
Set SentItems = ns.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objRecipient, olFolderSentMail).Items

I checked permissions and even given myself owner level permissions of the shared inbox.

Do you have the same permissions on the Sent Items folder from that mailbox? Can the folders be opened from Outlook itself (File | Open | Other User's folder)?

Edit the post indicating the line with the error when you step with F8. First break the .Items line into two.
Set myInbox = ns.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objRecipient, olFolderInbox) then Set myInboxItems = myInbox.Items. Set mySentFolder = ns.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objRecipient, olFolderSentMail) then Set mySentItems = mySentFolder .Items.

@DmitryStreblechenko I do have the same permissions on the sent item folder and I can view it from within Outlook itself, yes.

Not just view from Outlook, but doing what your code does - File | Open | Other User's folder

If someone would be able to explain why this works I would be most grateful.
But instead of accessing the olSentItems folder directly, accessing it via the Parent folder of olFolderInbox instead seems to work fine.
So instead of using -
Set SentItems = ns.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objRecipient, olFolderSentMail).Items

Replacing it with -
Set SentFolder = ns.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objRecipient, olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders("Sent Items")
Set SentItems = SentFolder.Items

Seems to work fine.

Most likely that means Outlook cannot access the message store - Sent Items entry id is stored in PR_IPM_SENTMAIL_ENTRYID property on the store. If the property is missing or the store cannot be accessed, you end up with that error. As for your workaround, keep in mind that "Sent Items" folder name is locale specific, so your code will fail for locales other than English.
